# How does legend() work on a dynamic data set?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I need a legend for a code which generates data from a dict. I don't know how much keys exist in the dict is there a way to do 'dynamic' a legend on this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for host in d.keys():
  plt.plot(range(100),d[host])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, then sure: you simply need to turn the key into a label somehow, even if it's as simple as calling str on it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x = numpy.arange(10.)
d = dict((i, numpy.sin(x+i)) for i in range(5))

for k in sorted(d):  # sort purely to make deterministic
    plt.plot(x,d[k],label=str(k))

plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.draw()
```

[image]